# Inversion of css rules

Tags: css

I'm searching for maybe existing processor of css which help me apply inverted kind of thinking in css. I want apply something like that

```
(margin-left:50px;font-weight:bold):{
    .top-header;
    .fother>.first;
}
```

On some layout it help me think more clear.

Comment: How is this different than .top-header, fother > .first { margin-left:50px} ?

Comment: @Xeli I think he wants to apply these classes to all elements that have `margin-left:50px` and `font-weight:bold` but I *may be* wrong. @RobertW Can you explain your question better?

Comment: You should not do this. Think about the developer who will maintain this. Why not rethink your logic ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [less](http://lesscss.org/) to make something similar happen see this example

```
.someclass {
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    .top-header;
    .fother;
}
```

This would make every element with .someclass also have the css rules of .top-header and .fother